# How can I most easily/quickly run the liftweb demo apps?

Tags: scala, lift

I'm attempting to run the liftweb demo apps, available [here](http://github.com/lift/examples/). The build instructions, [here](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Building_Lift), imply that I can compile them with a single command, but when I try, I get an error complaining about not being able to find the other parts of the framework, so I presume I have to run the superbuild.

I've tried that, and, after following the implied (but not stated) step of downloading all the main repositories to a directory, running it appears to work, but takes a ridiculously long time - 6 hours after starting the build, I left work with it still running. Coming back in on Monday I'm faced with this message:

```
[info] == lift-squeryl-record / test-start ==
[info] == lift-squeryl-record / test-start ==
[info] 
[info] == lift-squeryl-record / net.liftweb.squerylrecord.SquerylRecordSpec ==
17:39:08.409 [Finalizer] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.t.ThreadSafeClientConnManager - Shutting down
[info] == lift-squeryl-record / net.liftweb.squerylrecord.SquerylRecordSpec ==
Exception in thread "Thread-1735" Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError occurred dispatching signal Unknown Signal to handler- the VM may need to be forcibly terminated
```

The build process was stalled, and I had to terminate it. To boot, it seems 'buildall' does a clean before starting.

My questions are twofold:

1. Should the liftweb build process really take that long? What could be making it so incredibly slow? My build machine is only a Mac Mini, but I wouldn't expect anything to take this long - I could've built the linux kernel a dozen or more times in the time it took liftweb to (mostly) compile.
2. Is there a way to build the sample apps that doesn't involve building the whole lift framework from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to build any part of the Lift framework in order to use it. SBT will simply download the bits you declare as dependencies and build your code.

The build instructions you reference are for the Lift Framework build - probably only used by the developers that work on the releases.

The examples project you referenced contains lots of (every?) example projects - probably a little more than most people want to get started with. I cloned the repository and ran following commands:

1. `liftsh` - launches SBT
2. `update` - downloads dependencies
3. `jetty-run` - compiles and runs the examples (the 
   first one grabs the port - we
   probably have to select a specific
   sub project with SBT)

This took me about 10 minutes on a notebook and ended with hello Lift running on localhost:8080

A much lighter weight way to get started is to clone:
https://github.com/lift/lift_24_sbt/tree/master/scala_29/lift_basic

run:

1. `sbt`
2. `update`
3. `jetty-run`

This takes only a couple of minutes.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason, using `./liftsh +update +clean +deliver` as recommended in the docs failed, but this worked. A couple of questions: How can I build an app without running jetty, and where does it put the output? I ask because I need to run the apps in an environment other than Jetty.

Comment: Never mind, found it - the action is `deliver`, and the output is into the 'target' directory of the relevant sample. Thanks again!

Comment: As you found out Jetty is the default for development ( ~prepare-webapp is great for instant update of your app). SBT can produce a standard war file for deployment in other servlet containers.